# Recurrences where masters method doesnt apply

Tags: recursion, complexity-theory

Suppose you have a reoccurence defined by: `T(n) = T(n/2)  +1`. How does one evaluate this without master's method? What I have so far:

T(n) = T(n/2) + 1
T(n/2) = T(n/4) + 1
T(n/4) = T(n/8) + 1
...
T(1) = 1

It looks like this would be O(logn). Is this the only way to do these problems where master
s theorem does not occur?

Answer (score 0):

How you got this `T(1) = 1`?
Lets see:

```
T(0) = T(0/2) + 1 => 0 = 1!
```

So the `T(x)` function have an asymptote at `x=0`.
Please notice that we can redefine it to:

```
T(2^(x+1)) = T(2^x) + 1 
=> 
f(x+1) = f(x) + 1 
=> 
f(x) = x + a
=>
T(n) = Log2(n) + a(n)
```

where `a(n)` is a function with interval length 1

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think the Master Method doesn't apply? We have:

```
T(n) = a T(n/b) + f(n)
```

with

```
a = 1, b = 2, f(n) = 1
```

We can see that

```
c = log_b a = log_2 1 = 0
f(n) = 1 = Theta(1) = Theta(n^0 log^0 n) = Theta(n^c log^k n)
```

So we can use the result that

```
T(n) = Theta(n^c log^(k+1) n) = Theta(n^0 log^(0+1) n) = Theta(log n)
```

Which is your result.